# Changes to Pushpin.Location Inside ObservableCollection Don't Affect The Pushpin Until Map Is Redrawn

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, geolocation, mvvm-light, bing-maps

First question here, so far I've received great help just reading the answers. This is something I couldn't find any answers on though. So here comes...

We have a Bing Maps map whose `MapItemsControl` is bound to `ObservableCollection<Pushpin>` `Property`. When adding/removing items to the collection the map gets updated correctly.

Now my question is this: **how to update/bind the location of a `Pushpin` inside the collection so it is reflected on the map without redrawing the map by moving/zooming?**

Here is the Map.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplication ...
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
    <maps:Map ...>
        <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MapItems}"/>
    </maps:Map>
</phone:PhoneApplication>
```

MainViewModel.xaml:

```
#region MapItems

#region MapItems Property

/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="MapItems" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string MapItemsPropertyName = "MapItems";

private ObservableCollection<Pushpin> _MapItems =
    new ObservableCollection<Pushpin>();

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the MapItems property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<Pushpin> MapItems
{
    get
    {
        return _MapItems;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_MapItems == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _MapItems = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(MapItemsPropertyName);
    }
}

#endregion

#region OwnLocation

private Pushpin OwnLocation;

private void InitializeOwnLocation()
{
    OwnLocation = new Pushpin()
    {
        Style = App.Current.Resources["OwnLocationStyle"] as Style
    };
    Binding b = new Binding {
        Path = new PropertyPath("LastKnownLocation")
    };
    OwnLocation.SetBinding(Pushpin.LocationDependencyProperty, b);
    MapItems.Add(OwnLocation);
}

#endregion

...

#endregion
```

`LastKnownLocation` is being set in the `PositionChanged` of the `GeoCoordinateWatcher`

---

Update (30.5.2012 20.35). Implementation of `LastKnownLocation` property.

```
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="LastKnownLocation" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string LastKnownLocationPropertyName = "LastKnownLocation";

private GeoCoordinate _LastKnownLocation;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the LastKnownLocation property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public GeoCoordinate LastKnownLocation
{
    get
    {
        return _LastKnownLocation;
    }

    private set
    {
        if (_LastKnownLocation == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        var oldValue = _LastKnownLocation;
        _LastKnownLocation = value;
        Settings["LastKnownLocation"] = _LastKnownLocation;
        RaisePropertyChanged(LastKnownLocationPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's because Pushpin does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: So should I create an extension and implement the interface?

Comment: Since Pushpin.Location is a Dependency Property, it does not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to participate in Databinding.  koodimyyra can you show your implementation of the LastKnownLocation Property?

Comment: Extension and interface was too much for me... After long Googling I finally came to this [workaround](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/73266/448567.aspx#448567). The trick is to call `SetView` on the map view after changing `Pushpin` `Location`. Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: @BojinLi Updated question. There isn't anything special in there. The broadcasted message is used to trigger `SetView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented earlier after long Googling I finally came to a workaround that doesn't seem to be available anymore. The trick is to call `SetView` on the map view after changing `Pushpin.Location`.

Answer (score 0):

x:Name= myMap on map Control

When you want to rebind your map pins

set 
myMap.Children.Clear()

then re-add your Pins.

you can notify your data change

Comment: I see what you mean here. The problem with this approach is I don't want to clear the list every time one of the items is updated. The list has possibly tens or hundreds of items (public transit vehicles) and recreating it every time would be huge drawback. Or would it?